# Best IDE for javascript server development

Tags: javascript, ide, node.js, commonjs

After reading
http://www.pragprog.com/magazines/2010-03/javascript-its-not-just-for-browsers-any-more
I'm wondering which is the best IDE to develop server-side javascript applications?

I want a nice development environment with `commonjs` and `node` etc. Preferably windows but anything is interesting really. Is there any IDE with some nifty refactoring tools, maybe some intellisense-like function, etc etc.. Or is it notepad++ ftw?

Comment: You should use WebStorm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use Aptana 1.5 its very similar to eclipse which I use @ my work every day

Comment: 1 vote for saying what I was going to say :-) though aptana studio 2.0 is even better

Comment: Does Aptana actually have navigation/code assist that works? When I looked at it, it couldn't look inside functions. Since many frameworks are using self-executing anonymous functions, being unable to look inside them is a serious limitation

Comment: @Sean McMillan yes it does have home navigation and code assist